# How to get tf-idf matrix of a large size corpus, where features are pre-specified?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a corpus consisting 3,500,000 text documents. I want to construct a tf-idf matrix of (3,500,000 * 5,000) size. Here I have 5,000 distinct features (words).

I am using `scikit` `sklearn` in python. Where I am using `TfidfVectorizer` to do that. I have constructed a dictionary of 5000 size(one for each feature). While initializing the  `TfidfVectorizer` I am setting the parameter `vocabulary` with the dictionary of features. But while calling the `fit_transform`, it is showing some memory-map and then "CORE DUMP".

1. Does `TfidfVectorizer` perform well for a fixed vocabulary and large corpus?
2. If not, then what are the other options?

Comment: The answer to (1) is "yes, on my box it does". Consider opening an [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Other option can be [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim) it is very efficient in terms of memory and is very fast.
Here is the [link](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut2.html) to its tf-idf tutorial for your corpus.